# Gatling :- Read Multiple JSON Payload from single file

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections, gatling

I'm making many HTTP request with JSON Payload and I'm reading one file for every single request to get JSON Payload as below.

```
  postPayload1 = val postPayload = ElFileBody("Test_case1.json")

  val TC1 = feed(accountNumberFeeder1)
    .exec(http(testCase1).post(appendPathToUrl).headers(common_header).body(postPayload).asJSON
    .check(status.is(200)
    )
```

But, it becomes so many JSON files inside my resources directory now. So can I merge all my JSON together in one file as below.

```
{"testCase1":{
  "activationSource": "HH",
  "accountStatus": null,
}
}

{"testCase2":{
  "activationSource": "HH",
  "accountStatus": null,
}
}
```

and access it with my keys "testCase1", "testCase2" etc ?

```
val postPayload = ElFileBody("Test_case.json")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official Gatling Documentation, I found http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.1/session/feeder.html

**JSON feeders**
Some might want to use data in JSON format instead of CSV:

```
val jsonFileFeeder = jsonFile("foo.json")
val jsonUrlFeeder = jsonUrl("http://me.com/foo.json")
```

For example, the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id":19434,
    "foo":1
  },
  {
    "id":19435,
    "foo":2
  }
]
```

will be turned into:

```
record1: Map("id" -> 19434, "foo" -> 1)
record2: Map("id" -> 19435, "foo" -> 2)
```

Note that the root element has of course to be an array.